# Padding with Letters and Symbols

Tags: javascript, padding

I'm wondering how to go about padding with things that aren't zeros, mainly letters and punctuation.

I am working with a database that creates reports (based on information in the database) that can then be exported to a csv file to use in excel.  I noticed that both the database and excel drop any leading zeros from the numbers we have (one of the things in every reports is an ID number, which is 7 digits and often will have zeros at the front, like 0123456 or 0012345).

The database allows calculated columns with javascript so, based on the information I found on this website I made a calculated column and added a script to pad the numbers with zeros, which fixes it in the database but not in excel. What I'm hoping to do is pad it not only with zeros, but with an apostrophe so when exporting to excel it will show up as '0123456 which should force excel to keep the leading zeros (according to various excel tutorials I found, adding an apostrophe in front of the number switches it to text).

So far the two ways of adding leading zeros that worked for my program are:

```
var x=PersonID;
var y="0000000";
(y + x).slice(-7);
```

where PersonID pulls up the file for the ID's

or

```
var str =PersonID;
var pad ="0000000";
(pad+str).slice(-7)
```

or

```
var n=PersonID;
("000000" + n).slice(-7);
```

however when I switch "0000000" to "'0000000" or '\'0000000' (and -7 to -8) it just adds an extra zero!! Thinking it was a problem with the apostrophe I tried "A0000000" but it just switched the A into yet another zero.  Is there any way to pad numbers with non numerical info?

Sorry this is a little long, I just wanted to give all the information on my situation. Thanks in advance to anyone who knows a solution to this : )

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because when you slice you are removing the front characters, which includes your leading "A" or "'".  Try this:

```
var str =PersonID;
var pad ="0000000";
"A" + (pad+str).slice(-7)
```

Comment: For some reason when I try this the column that should be filled with a list of all the IDs is now blank. For some reason this happens whenever I tried solutions that had var str and var pad in them.  Is there something I should put in front of this so that the program interprets it?  Sorry if that's a silly question, I've never used javascript before this morning so this is all new to me.

Comment: I think I got it! Ok so I figured out that putting "A" in front on it's own didn't work but if I made another line that said var x="A" and then underneath x + (pad+str).slice(-7) it worked! I think it was just a matter of modifying it to fit with what the program accepted.  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you put a character at the front of the pad then it will inevitably be stripped off given that your ID is probably at least 1 character long.

```
var id = "A0000000123"
id.slice(-7); //id = 0000123
```

If you want to pad with anything other than 0 then just make that your 'pad' value;

```
var pad = "AAAAAAA";
var n = pad + PersonID; //123
var paddedId = n.slice(-7) //paddedId = "AAAA123"
```

Perhaps what you really want is to take the first N characters from your pad instead of the last N.

```
var pad = "A000000";
var PersonID = "123";
var toTake = pad.length - PersonID.length; //number of characters to take for the pad
var paddedId = pad.slice(0,toTake) + PersonID;// "A000123"
```

Comment: hmmm, when I tried these I either got an error message or instead of a column filled with the IDs I got a column filled with [object . Not sure what that means. I think the last solution you put up (taking the first N character) should work but I can't quite figure it out.  Where is the "123" from var PersonID = "123"; coming from?

Comment: I tried     var PersonID = PersonID as well (If I want to use any of the IDs I have to put the name of the column so the program knows to pull data from there) but that just got me an error message.

Comment: "123" is just an example of what the value could be that you're trying to pad. I'm assuming **PersonID** is the value that needs to be padded, so you would just exclude the **var PersonID = "123";** portion. What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I tried it that way but I keep getting [object instead of the list of IDs.  Is there some sort of code I should be adding to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Without seeing the code that you are using to write the values to the DB I can't help you. Also without the error message I can't help you further. The code I posted above works by itself ([link to js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAvrL/)). Perhaps you can update your question to include the 'write to database' portion.

Comment: oh and the error message is just a red exclamation point.  That usually happens when it can't process the javascript. Weirdly, I've gotten that error with solutions that I've copy and pasted from people who say they work so I think maybe they aren't lining up with how the program holds it's data?

Comment: The code provided are examples not meant to be strictly copy/pasted into your program. You need to look at the examples and think logically about how it applies to your code...and then apply it to your code. The red exclamation point is an indication that there is an error. Depending on the browser you are using you can further inspect exactly what error happened. Usually by hitting **F12** you can open a developer console and get more information.

Comment: Ok so I think the error message and [object messages are coming because there isn't any formula at the end of these.  What I've notices is that the scripts that work have var blah blah and var whatever and then the last line is some sort of formula.  So when I try the last solution you suggested because it ends with    var paddedID = pad.slice(0,toTake) + PersonID;  and so it doesn't work because it's just setting up another variable.  When I try it but remove    var paddedID = from the front then it works but it just gives the number without leading zeros. Is there another formula I'm missing

Comment: Hi, I just left comment above but I managed to modify Bill Ticehurst's suggestion to fit my problem, and it seems to be working.  Thanks though : )

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting [Object object], then either `pad` or `PersonID` is an object and you have to convert it to a string. A simple `n.toString()` should do the trick but `(n+"")` I hear is faster.

Also, just changing the column or row you are reporting into to the Text format instead of the default, General format should also help.

I know I am late to the party, but hopefully this helps someone!